# Why does user account is being used but not the Service Principal?

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-cli, azure-service-principal

I have logged in using my account "emj" and executed the following Azure CLIs on Jenkins

```
az account show
az login --service-principal -u <<UserName>> -p <<Password>> -t <tenantID>>
az account set -s <<Subscription-123>>
az account show
```

and below is the output

it showed the user account as expected

```
+ az account show
{
  "environmentName": "AzureCloud",
  "homeTenantId": "tenantID",
  "id": "Subscription-123-ID",
  "isDefault": true,
  "managedByTenants": [],
  "name": "Subscription-123",
  "state": "Enabled",
  "tenantId": "tenantID",
  "user": {
    "name": "emj@demo.com",
    "type": "user"
  }
}
```

logged in as a service principal

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ az login --service-principal -u <<UserName>> -p <<Password>> -t <tenantID>>
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "tenantID",
    "id": "Subscription-456-ID",
    "isDefault": true,
    "managedByTenants": [],
    "name": "Subscription-456",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "tenantID",
    "user": {
      "name": "servicePrincipalID",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  },
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "tenantID",
    "id": "Subscription-789-ID",
    "isDefault": false,
    "managedByTenants": [
      {
        "tenantId": "tenantID"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Subscription-789",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "tenantID",
    "user": {
      "name": "servicePrincipalID",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  }
]
```

and set the required subscription

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ az account set -s <<Subscription-456-ID>>
```

while I was expecting to show the service principal, it showed the user account

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ az account show
{
  "environmentName": "AzureCloud",
  "homeTenantId": "tenantID",
  "id": "Subscription-456-ID",
  "isDefault": true,
  "managedByTenants": [],
  "name": "Subscription-456",
  "state": "Enabled",
  "tenantId": "tenantID",
  "user": {
    "name": "emj@demo.com",
    "type": "user"
  }
}
```

**Note:** If don't set the subscription using "az account set -s <>", it shows the service principal account.

why does it show the user account instead of the Service Principal? what is the meaning of 'az login --service-principal -u <> -p <> -t >' as it is not taken into account?

Comment: Couple questions: Are you still logged in to your user account, and if so, does your user account have access to the same subscription or does only the service principal have access to it?

Comment: Yes, still the user account is logged in and it has access on all the subscription which we are planning to revoke once we are able to  perform the operations using the service principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not sure why it happened, but to solve this issue, you could use [`az account clear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az_account_clear) before login the user account/service principal, then the different contexts will not be mixed.

For example, you want to run the Azure CLI via the service principal credential, it should be:

```
az account clear
az login --service-principal -u <<ApplicationId>> -p <<Password>> -t <tenantID>>
az account set -s <<Subscription-456-ID>>
az account show
```

Then if you want to do operations via the user credential, simply use the command like:

```
az account clear
az login --service-principal -u <<UserName>> -p <<Password>> -t <tenantID>>
az account set -s <<Subscription-123>>
az account show
```